# Cython build for python-debug under Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I'm trying to build a Cython version compatible with the python-debug. I managed to compile Python 3.6.2 and the recent Cython 0.26.1 with VS 2017 C++ compiler. However, when I try to run cython, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Python-3.6.2-build\Scripts\cython-script.py", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('Cython==0.26.1', 'console_scripts', 'cython')()
File "d:\Python-3.6.2-build\lib\site-packages\setuptools-33.1.1-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
File "d:\Python-3.6.2-build\lib\site-packages\setuptools-33.1.1-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
File "d:\Python-3.6.2-build\lib\site-packages\setuptools-33.1.1-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2291, in load
File "d:\Python-3.6.2-build\lib\site-packages\setuptools-33.1.1-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
File "d:\Python-3.6.2-build\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 28, in <module>
from .Scanning import PyrexScanner, FileSourceDescriptor
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It seems there's an issue with importing the Scanning module, which is the dynamic library, in fact. In my *Python\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler* I have the followng files related to this module:

- Scanning.pxd
- Scanning.py
- Scanning_d.cp36-win32.pyd

I tried to rename the latter one to Scanning_d.pyd, but this did not change the situation. Did anyone face a similar issue?

Comment: Have you tried using VS 2015 C++ compiler?